# Deleting from DataTable disables data-toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to create a page that populates a DataTable via a modal on a screen. Overall, I can add, edit, and remove to the datatable. However, after removing from the DataTable, the add functionality stops working. Can tell me what is happening?

```
<form name="create" action="" role="form" class="smart-wizard form-horizontal" id="form" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <!-- start: PAGE CONTENT -->
    <div class="row" id="form-container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <!-- start: FORM WIZARD PANEL -->
            <div id="wizard" class="swMain">

                <!-- Misc form data, should not be relevant -->

                <div id="step-2">
                    <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 2 Content</h2>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <i class="fa fa-external-link-square"></i>
                                Locations
                                <div class="panel-tools">
                                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-link panel-collapse collapses" href="#"> </a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-link panel-config" href="#panel-config" data-toggle="modal"> <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> </a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-link panel-refresh" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> </a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-link panel-expand" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-resize-full"></i> </a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-link panel-close" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i> </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 space20">
                                        <a href="#responsive-1" data-toggle="modal" class="new-modal btn btn-green">
                                                    Add New <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="sample_2">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Stop #</th>
                                                <th>Street Address</th>
                                                <th>City</th>
                                                <th>State</th>
                                                <th>Zip</th>
                                                <th>Pickup Weight</th>
                                                <th>Delivery Weight</th>
                                                <th>Arrival Date</th>
                                                <th>Delete</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <!--- Content created by datatable -->
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-light-grey back-step btn-block">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-arrow-left"></i> Back
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                                Finish <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                            
            <!-- end: FORM WIZARD PANEL -->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


        <!-- end: RIGHT SIDEBAR -->
        <!-- javascript includes are here -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".new-modal").click(function(){
                    create_modal($('#sample_2').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length + 1);  
                });     
                $('#sample_2').on('click', '.delete-row', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    //Get ID of the modal being deleted
                    modal_id = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();

                    //Update modal to indicate value was deleted
                    $('#locations-' + modal_id + '-retired').val("True");

                    //Get stop number being removed
                    stop_number = $(this).closest('tr').find(".stop-number").val()

                    //Update stop #
                    $('.stop-number').each(function(){
                        if($(this).val() > stop_number) {
                            $(this).val($(this).val() - 1);
                        }
                    });

                    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
                    $('#sample_2').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(tr.index());
                });
                $( document ).on('click', '.edit-modal', function(e) {
                    modal_id = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
                    $('#responsive-' + $.trim(modal_id)).find('.save-modal').text("Update");
                    $('#responsive-' + $.trim(modal_id)).find('.save-modal').addClass("update-modal");
                    $('#responsive-' + $.trim(modal_id)).find('.update-modal').removeClass("save-modal");
                });
            });

            $( document ).on( "focus", "input.date-picker", function() {
                $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                        autoclose: true,
                        format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
                        minDate: 0
                    });
            });

            $( document ).on( "click", ".save-modal", function() {

                var count = $('#sample_2').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length + 1;
                $('#sample_2').dataTable().fnAddData( [
                     '<input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + ($('#sample_2').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length + 1) + '-stop_number\" name=\"locations-' + ($('#sample_2').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length + 1) + '-stop_number\" class=\"form-control stop-number\" value=\"' + ($('#sample_2').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length + 1) + '\"> <p style=\"display:none;\" class=\"modal-id\">' + ($('#sample_2').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length + 1) + '<\/p>',
                    $('#locations-' + count + '-address1').val(),
                     $('#locations-' + count + '-city').val(),
                    $('#locations-' + count + '-state').val(),
                    $('#locations-' + count + '-postal_code').val(),
                    $('#locations-' + count + '-pickup_weight').val(),
                    $('#locations-' + count + '-delivery_weight').val(),
                    $('#locations-' + count + '-arrival_date').val(),
                    '<a class=\"edit-modal\" href=\"#responsive-' + ($('#sample_2').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length + 1) + '\" data-toggle=\"modal\">Edit<\/a>/<a class=\"delete-row\" href=\"\">Delete<\/a>' ]
                );

                $('.new-modal').prop('href', '#responsive-' + (count + 1));



            }); 

            $( document ).on( "click", ".update-modal", function() {
                var modal_id = $(this).closest(".modal.fade").children("p").text();
                //alert($(this).closest(".form-control.stop-number").length);
                $('#sample_2').dataTable().fnUpdate( 
                    ['<input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + modal_id + '-stop_number\" class=\"form-control stop-number\" value=\"' + modal_id + '\"> <p style=\"display:none;\" class=\"modal-id\">' + modal_id + '<\/p>', 
                    $('#locations-' + modal_id + '-address1').val(),
                     $('#locations-' + modal_id + '-city').val(),
                    $('#locations-' + modal_id + '-state').val(),
                    $('#locations-' + modal_id + '-postal_code').val(),
                    $('#locations-' + modal_id + '-pickup_weight').val(),
                    $('#locations-' + modal_id + '-delivery_weight').val(),
                    $('#locations-' + modal_id + '-arrival_date').val(),
                    '<a class=\"edit-modal\" href=\"#responsive-' + modal_id + '\" data-toggle=\"modal\">Edit<\/a>/<a class=\"delete-row\" href=\"\">Delete<\/a>'
                    ], $('td').filter(function() {
                            return $(this).children("p").text() == modal_id;
                        }).closest('tr').index());
            }); 

            function create_modal(index){
                alert('creating modal: ' + index);
                var modal = '<div id=\"responsive-' + index + '\" class=\"modal fade\" tabindex=\"-1\" data-width=\"840\" style=\"display: none;\">' +
                               ' <p style=\"display:none;\" class=\"modal-id\">' + index + '<\/p>' + 
                            '    <div class=\"modal-header\" id=\"modal-header\">' +
                            '        <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-hidden=\"true\">' +
                            '            &times;' +
                            '        <\/button>' +
                            '        <h4 class=\"modal-title\">Add Location<\/h4>' +
                            '    <\/div>' +
                            '    <div class=\"modal-body\">' +
                            '        <div class=\"row\">' +
                            '            <div class=\"panel panel-default\">' +
                            '                <div class=\"panel-heading\">' +
                            '                    <i class=\"fa fa-external-link-square\"><\/i>' +
                            '                    Location - ' + index + '' +
                            '                <\/div>' +
                            '                <div class=\"panel-body\">' +
                            '                    <div class=\"row\">' +
                            '                        <div class=\"col-md-12\">' +
                            '                            <h4>General<\/h4>' +
                            '                            <hr>' +
                            '                            <input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + index + '-retired\" name=\"locations-' + index + '-retired\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"'+index+'\">' +
                            '                            <div class=\"form-group\">' +
                            '                                <label class=\"col-sm-3 control-label\">' +
                            '                                    Address <span class=\"symbol required\"><\/span>' +
                            '                                <\/label>' +
                            '                                <div class=\"col-sm-7\">' +
                            '                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + index + '-address1\" name=\"locations-' + index + '-address1\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"\">' +
                            '                                <\/div>' +
                            '                            <\/div>' +
                            '                            <div class=\"form-group\">' +
                            '                                <label class=\"col-sm-3 control-label\">' +
                            '                                    City <span class=\"symbol required\"><\/span>' +
                            '                                <\/label>' +
                            '                                <div class=\"col-sm-7\">' +
                            '                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + index + '-city\" name=\"locations-' + index + '-city\" class=\"form-control\">' +
                            '                                <\/div>' +
                            '                            <\/div>' +
                            '                            <div class=\"form-group\">' +
                            '                                <label class=\"col-sm-3 control-label\">' +
                            '                                    State <span class=\"symbol required\"><\/span>' +
                            '                                <\/label>' +
                            '                                <div class=\"col-sm-7\">' +
                            '                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + index + '-state\" name=\"locations-' + index + '-state\" class=\"form-control\">' +
                            '                                <\/div>' +
                            '                            <\/div>' +
                            '                            <div class=\"form-group\">' +
                            '                                <label class=\"col-sm-3 control-label\">' +
                            '                                    Zip Code <span class=\"symbol required\"><\/span>' +
                            '                                <\/label>' +
                            '                                <div class=\"col-sm-7\">' +
                            '                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + index + '-postal_code\" name=\"locations-' + index + '-postal_code\" class=\"form-control\"\>' +
                            '                                <\/div>' +
                            '                            <\/div>' +
                            '                            <div class=\"form-group\">' +
                            '                                <label class=\"col-sm-3 control-label\">' +
                            '                                    Arrival Date <span class=\"symbol required\"><\/span>' +
                            '                                <\/label>' +
                            '                                <div class=\"col-sm-7\">' +
                            '                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + index + '-arrival_date\" name=\"locations-' + index + '-arrival_date\" data-date-format=\"dd-mm-yyyy\" data-date-viewmode=\"years\" class=\"form-control date-picker\">' +
                            '                                <\/div>' +
                            '                            <\/div>' +
                            '                        <\/div>' +
                            '                    <\/div>' +
                            '                    <div class=\"row\"><hr><\/div>' +
                            '                    <div class=\"row\">' +
                            '                        <div class=\"col-md-12\">' +
                            '                            <h4>Receiver<\/h4>' +
                            '                            <hr>' +
                            '                            <div class=\"form-group\">' +
                            '                                <label class=\"col-sm-3 control-label\">' +
                            '                                    Name <span class=\"symbol required\"><\/span>' +
                            '                                <\/label>' +
                            '                                <div class=\"col-sm-7\">' +
                            '                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + index + '-contact_name\" name=\"locations-' + index + '-contact_name\" class=\"form-control\"\>' +
                            '                                <\/div>' +
                            '                            <\/div>' +
                            '                            <div class=\"form-group\">' +
                            '                                <label class=\"col-sm-3 control-label\">' +
                            '                                    Phone <span class=\"symbol required\"><\/span>' +
                            '                                <\/label>' +
                            '                                <div class=\"col-sm-7\">' +
                            '                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + index + '-contact_phone\" name=\"locations-' + index + '-contact_phone\" class=\"form-control\"\>' +
                            '                                <\/div>' +
                            '                            <\/div>' +
                            '                        <\/div>' +
                            '                    <\/div>' +
                            '                    <div class=\"row\"><hr><\/div>' +
                            '                    <div class=\"row\">' +
                            '                        <div class=\"col-md-6\">' +
                            '                            <h4>Pickup<\/h4>' +
                            '                            <hr>' +
                            '                            <div class=\"form-group\">' +
                            '                                <label class=\"col-sm-3 control-label\">' +
                            '                                    Weight <span class=\"symbol required\"><\/span>' +
                            '                                <\/label>' +
                            '                                <div class=\"col-sm-7\">' +
                            '                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + index + '-pickup_weight\" name=\"locations-' + index + '-pickup_weight\" class=\"form-control\">' +
                            '                                <\/div>' +
                            '                            <\/div>' +
                            '                        <\/div>' +
                            '                        <div class=\"col-md-6\">' +
                            '                            <h4>Delivery<\/h4>' +
                            '                            <hr>' +
                            '                            <div class=\"form-group\">' +
                            '                                <label class=\"col-sm-3 control-label\">' +
                            '                                    Weight <span class=\"symbol required\"><\/span>' +
                            '                                <\/label>' +
                            '                                <div class=\"col-sm-7\">' +
                            '                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"locations-' + index + '-delivery_weight\" name=\"locations-' + index + '-delivery_weight\" class=\"form-control\">' +
                            '                                <\/div>' +
                            '                            <\/div>' +
                            '                        <\/div>' +
                            '                    <\/div>' +
                            '                <\/div>' +
                            '            <\/div>' +
                            '        <\/div>' +
                            '    <\/div>' +
                            '    <div class=\"modal-footer\">' +
                            '   <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"locations-' + ($('#sample_2').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length + 1) + '-stop_number\" name=\"locations-' + ($('#sample_2').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length + 1) + '-stop_number\" class=\"form-control stop-number\" value=\"' + ($('#sample_2').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length + 1) + '\">' +
                            '        <button type=\"button\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" class=\"btn btn-light-grey\">' +
                            '            Close' +
                            '        <\/button>' +
                            '        <button type=\"button\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" class=\"btn btn-blue save-modal\">' +
                            '            Add' +
                            '        <\/button>' +
                            '    <\/div>' +
                            '<\/div>'
                $("#form-container").append(modal);
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was recreating modals with the same idea in my create_modal entity. I changed it from:

```
$(".new-modal").click(function(){
    create_modal($('#sample_2').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length + 1);
});
```

To:

```
$(".new-modal").click(function(){
    create_modal($('.modal.fade').length + 1);
});
```